# Setup cancancan that user couldn't destroy itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I'm setting up cancancan to implement this function:
if the user is admin, it can destroy every user but himself.
This is my ability.rb

```
 class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
    if user.role == 'admin'
      cannot :destroy, User, id: user.id
    end
    end
end
```

And here's my view

```
<h1>Listing Users</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>E-Mail</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.role %></td>
        <% if can? :destroy, @user %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And even with this setup there's no destroy link at the end of every user now. What I want is that there's a destroy link behind every users but the admin himself. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're calling `if can? :destroy, @user` when `@user` doesn't exist:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if can? :destroy, user %>
<% end %>
```

---

If the original answer does not work, perhaps you'd be better using a [`block`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#only-for-object-attributes) to evaluate the `user` object:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    case user.role
      when "admin"
        cannot :destroy, User do |x|
          x.id == user.id
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } if can? :destroy, user %>
```

... although fixing the first issue, I think, will resolve your issue.

Comment: Still do not let me delete the user

Answer (score 0):

Just because an admin cannot destroy itself, does not give it permission to destroy other users. You could try giving it destroy permissions.

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.role == 'admin'
      cannot :destroy, User, id: user.id
    else
      can :destroy, User
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Still the same, no destroy links next to all the user info